# Setting of yii admin section

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii-url-manager

I want to create admin panel in my existing yii project. For this, I am using [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior).

Now I am able to access "localhost/dir/backend.php". I want to this url as "localhost/dir/backend" and also want to url management for login and other link in admin.
My config file code is

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        'admin' => 'site/index',
        'admin/<_c>' => '<_c>',
        'admin/<_c>/<_a>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
    ),
),
```

Please tell me how to access above url and login url and other url for admin.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your application on Apache, you need to add a .htaccess app root with the following rules

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```